# How to I read all existing CSV files on a server?

Tags: php, csv

This question is a little complicated, but I will try my best to explain.  Feel free to ask for clarification if my question does not make sense.

> **Situation:**
>
> On my server there will be a new CSV file added every day into a particular folder. The CSV files will all be kept in the same folder.  They will have a name consistant with the day.  For example **log_2013_05_24.csv**.
>
> **Objective:**
>
> I need to write a PHP program that will find all existing CSV files so that I can search through them. In the end I need to find all the dates that exist.

The data inside the CSV files looks similar to this:

```
4/14/13, 17:30:56, data, data, data, data
4/14/13, 17:31:06, data, data, data, data 
( ... about 10,000 of these ^ a new line for every 10 seconds all day )
```

I am using php explode to get the dates from my current CSV file.  This will produce an array of strings similar to: '4/14/13'.

But there are two problems:

1: They are strings, not dates

2: I don't know how to find all existing CSV files so that PHP can search them.

Comment: Are you open to another suggestion? I have something I could post that will read and list all `.csv` files from a set folder, in a `list` format. If you already have a function that creates the .csv files, this could be implemented into it, if desired. If `peterm's` answer is satisfactory, then by all means stick with it. Cheers

Comment: @Fred: I'm open to all suggestions. =) I do not have a program that will create the csv from their .txt files.  Someone else is working on that, so I will not have access to that code.
How will your code differ from `peterm's`?

Comment: I posted it below, hope it helps you in your project, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) class to create dates

```
$str = '04/14/13';
$date = new DateTime($str);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function to traverse filesystem

```
$files = glob('*.csv');
var_dump(files);
```

Sample output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "test.csv"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "test1.csv"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "test2.csv"
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! So I would do something similar to glob("*.csv") and that will find all the csv files in a directory?

Comment: @Willow Exactly. It will return an array of filenames matching the pattern in current directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse your string into a timestamp, then format that string into the format you need.  Look into using `strtotime()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and `date()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).
2. Make a bash script and grep for files that end in .csv (`grep -l *.csv /path/to/dir`), and that's a lowercase L.  Look at the man file for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: This is only a suggestive answer and am not taking away from `peterm's` answer, or anyone else's.**

If I may add, this would read and list all `CSV` files from a set folder, minus the extension.

This of course can easily be modified to also show the files' extension.

```
<?php

// You can add any other functions here such as file creation, etc.

$dir = 'csv_folder'; // The directory containing the files. 
$ext = '.csv'; // The file extension. 
?> 

<ul>
<?php foreach (glob($dir . '/*' . $ext) as $file) { ?> 
<li>
<a href="<?php echo "/" . $file ?>"><?php echo basename($file, $ext); ?></a>
</li>

<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

To show the files' extension, simply change this line:

```
<a href="<?php echo "/" . $file ?>"><?php echo basename($file, $ext); ?></a>
```

to

```
<a href="<?php echo "/" . $file ?>"><?php echo basename($file); ?></a>
```

by removing `, $ext`